# Private PoA Network doesn't mine

Tags: private-blockchain, proof-of-authority, clique, poa, digitalocean

I have 5 (8GB/4vCPU) droplets (private networking enabled; IP's below are of this private network) running on DigitalOcean. I am startled because the workflow I outline below worked like charm locally.

- OS: `4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- geth: `1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d`

The droplets have ufw enabled, however I opened all tcp/udp ports that are relevant for geth/ssh.

1. First, I dynamically generate a genesis block authorizing the 5 nodes as sealers and pre-allocating them with Ether (Also adding 100 other accounts for later use). (I have `extradata` and other attributes from puppeth)
2. After that, I make sure that geth isn't running and kill all bootnode or geth processes via SSH.
3. Then, I SCP the `genesis.json` and `identities.js` to all nodes. `identities.js` contains the 5 coinbase accounts.
4. I sucessfully `init` the genesis block on all nodes and start the bootnode on the first droplet.
5. Next up, it's time to start `geth`with the following command on each node:

   - $1 is passed in using bash (1-5) from `identities.js`
   - $2 is passed in using bash and is the internal IP of `en1` on the respective droplet

```
geth --datadir=/home/node/ --identity=$1 --port=30300 --rpc --rpccorsdomain=* --rpcapi admin,net,clique,eth,web3,miner,personal --rpcport=8500 --networkid=187 --preload=/home/identities.js --bootnodes enode://a349b003327c3075b779715a733d5076b986aae0225c48a760cd2b0e768b9654c0179014353ebb34eb0b9e7654caf69ec56d80b1b32705277bad953fb7777585@10.135.29.232:30301 --nodiscover --verbosity=6 --unlock 0 --password /home/password.sec --nat "extip:$2">> /home/node/console.log 2>&1 &
```

6. Because we have the `--nodiscover` flag, I add all nodes using a bash script to first collect `admin.nodeInfo` from every node, and then recursively use `admin.addPeer` via `ssh` and `geth --exec` which suceeeds returning `true` for every entry.
7. After that, we start mining on 3 out of 5 sealer nodes to reach consensus.

However, they never mine any blocks and just stay stuck in the following endless loop of `Recalculated downloader QoS values` even though they still have each other as peers when I check `admin.peers` and `net.peerCount`.
Also, checking `clique.getSigners()` sucessfully returns an array containing the pre-allocated and authorized nodes that are running and unlocked on the droplets.

The log-level output from geth with on all nodes looks like this:

```
TRACE[03-15|13:02:37] Registering sync peer                    peer=6c8d5ad9f798ede5
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:37] Relaxed downloader QoS values            rtt=20s confidence=0.333 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:38] Adding static node                       node="enode://f26f9b43bae5ff8018a723f714f045f55d74a438abf7f043a71c7bf758ebd7fbfa2d31f9bd8f74e06e1d6b0744476013f0a7bf324e06235881a3c1f29fbdad91@10.135.75.26:30300?discport=0"
TRACE[03-15|13:02:38] New dial task                            task="staticdial f26f9b43bae5ff80 10.135.75.26:30300"
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:38] Adding p2p peer                          id=f26f9b43bae5ff80 name=Geth/sealer05/v1.7.3...                                  addr=10.135.75.26:30300  peers=4
TRACE[03-15|13:02:38] Dial task done                           task="staticdial f26f9b43bae5ff80 10.135.75.26:30300"
TRACE[03-15|13:02:38] Starting protocol eth/63                 id=f26f9b43bae5ff80 conn=staticdial
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:38] Ethereum peer connected                  id=f26f9b43bae5ff80 conn=staticdial name=Geth/sealer05/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9.2
TRACE[03-15|13:02:38] Registering sync peer                    peer=f26f9b43bae5ff80
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:38] Relaxed downloader QoS values            rtt=20s confidence=0.250 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.625 ttl=1m0s
INFO [03-15|13:02:52] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [03-15|13:02:52] Starting mining operation
INFO [03-15|13:02:52] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=205.437µs
TRACE[03-15|13:02:52] Waiting for slot to sign and propagate   delay=-99.476ms
INFO [03-15|13:02:52] Successfully sealed new block            number=1 hash=4c706b…3edb3c
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:52] Trie cache stats after commit            misses=14 unloads=0
INFO [03-15|13:02:52]  mined potential block                  number=1 hash=4c706b…3edb3c
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:52] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[03-15|13:02:52] Propagated block                         hash=4c706b…3edb3c recipients=2 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
INFO [03-15|13:02:52] Commit new mining work                   number=2 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=601.597µs
INFO [03-15|13:02:52] Signed recently, must wait for others
TRACE[03-15|13:02:52] Announced block                          hash=4c706b…3edb3c recipients=2 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:52] Queued propagated block                  peer=6c8d5ad9f798ede5 number=1 hash=b88988…21011c queued=1
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:52] Importing propagated block               peer=6c8d5ad9f798ede5 number=1 hash=b88988…21011c
WARN [03-15|13:02:52] Discarded bad propagated block           number=1 hash=b88988…21011c
TRACE[03-15|13:02:52] Propagated block                         hash=b88988…21011c recipients=1 duration=848.472µs
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:52] Queued propagated block                  peer=3869118cfc562f9e number=1 hash=b88988…21011c queued=1
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:52] Importing propagated block               peer=3869118cfc562f9e number=1 hash=b88988…21011c
WARN [03-15|13:02:52] Discarded bad propagated block           number=1 hash=b88988…21011c
TRACE[03-15|13:02:52] Propagated block                         hash=b88988…21011c recipients=0 duration=370.18µs
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:53] Queued propagated block                  peer=3869118cfc562f9e number=1 hash=dffae0…4fe644 queued=1
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:53] Importing propagated block               peer=3869118cfc562f9e number=1 hash=dffae0…4fe644
WARN [03-15|13:02:54] Discarded bad propagated block           number=1 hash=dffae0…4fe644
TRACE[03-15|13:02:54] Propagated block                         hash=dffae0…4fe644 recipients=1 duration=1.629ms
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:54] Queued propagated block                  peer=05eb0ebc7dec7aa9 number=1 hash=dffae0…4fe644 queued=1
DEBUG[03-15|13:02:54] Importing propagated block               peer=05eb0ebc7dec7aa9 number=1 hash=dffae0…4fe644
WARN [03-15|13:02:54] Discarded bad propagated block           number=1 hash=dffae0…4fe644
TRACE[03-15|13:02:54] Propagated block                         hash=dffae0…4fe644 recipients=1 duration=739.317µs
TRACE[03-15|13:03:05] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (29.999994993s)"
TRACE[03-15|13:03:05] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (660.45357ms)"
TRACE[03-15|13:03:06] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (660.45357ms)"
TRACE[03-15|13:03:06] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (702.908968ms)"
TRACE[03-15|13:03:07] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (702.908968ms)"
TRACE[03-15|13:03:07] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (700.379857ms)"
TRACE[03-15|13:03:08] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (700.379857ms)"
DEBUG[03-15|13:03:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.812 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:03:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.906 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:03:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.953 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:04:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.977 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:04:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.988 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:04:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.994 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:05:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.997 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:05:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.999 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:05:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=0.999 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:06:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:06:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:06:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:07:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:07:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:07:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:08:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:08:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:08:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:09:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:09:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:09:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:10:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:10:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:10:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:11:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:11:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:11:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:12:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:12:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:12:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:13:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:13:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:13:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:14:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:14:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:14:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:15:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:15:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:15:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:16:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:16:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:16:48] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[03-15|13:17:08] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[03-15|13:17:28] Refreshing port mapping                  proto=tcp extport=30300 intport=30300 interface=ExtIP(10.135.29.232)
DEBUG[03-15|13:17:28] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
```

Is something inherently wrong with this approach? 
I really can't get any further. Any hint is highly appreciated since I really spent days trying to figure out a way to get this up and running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be resolved by only defining two out of 5 authorized sealers in the genesis.json (using puppeth) and only starting them with `--mine` and the other 3 nodes without it. We also added some sleep timers between the starting of the different geth instances, maybe that also helped.

If you ever experience a similar issue that doesn't conclude any networking issues you best refer to [EIP 225](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225) on github.

Answer (score 2):

Yo should pass `--mine` as parameter as shellcoder said. You can also send the order to mine from the geth client attached:

```
- geth attach node_directory/geth.ipc
> miner.start()
```

Remember that the account should be set as a sealer in the extradata field in genesis json.